# Any recommendation for rails workflow implementations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, workflow, state-machine

Anybody have experience with Rails workflow plugins?  [Route](http://openwferu.rubyforge.org/)/OpenWFEru.

I am looking for CMS type workflow with states like edit, submit, approve, rollback, based on roles.  Is this plugin overkill? Would I be better off just doing the same thing with a state machine (AASM) and acts as auditable/acts as versioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off with AASM or "workflow" ie a state-based tool (in the beginning at least).

Ruote makes more sense for "business processes" and not "resource lifecycle".

An interesting combination would be to use ruote to manage the state (via aasm / workflow) of multiple resources (documents if you like). Sometimes, a resource may belong to many business processes, and could perhaps exhibit more than one state.

It all depends on your requirements.

Comment: +1 for AASM; it's not perfect, but it's fairly widely used and under continuous development.

Answer (score 0):

I rolled a simpler alternative to AASM. Take a look at https://github.com/alternegro/flojo